# Getting date in specified format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting current date in format `"2013-02-10 09:26:52 +0000"` by using `[NSDate date]`.
I want date in format like `"Feb 10"`.

Can anyone suggest correct `dateFormat`?

Comment: And this has been asked many many times before... please search for "[objective-c] date format".

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter class:

```
NSDateFormatter * myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString * formattedDate = [myFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Here you have info to choose the output format for setDateFormat: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"2013-02-10 09:26:52 +0000"; // The date in a string

//Convert the string to date with the same format 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"]; // Set format
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];

//Create the new date format using NSDateFormatter 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"]; // Set format

//Convert the date using dateFormat1
NSDate *formatDate= [dateFormat1 dateFromString:date]; // date with MMM dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi set the date formatter like this

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

It is working in my case :

```
            NSDateFormatter* dateFormatterBegin = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatterBegin setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
            NSString *dateStringBegin = @"2013-02-10 09:26:52 +0000";
            NSDate* datebegin = [dateFormatterBegin dateFromString:[dateStringBegin stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(dateStringBegin.length-3, 1)]];
            [dateFormatterBegin setDateFormat:@"MMM-dd"];
            NSString *beginDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s%@","Start Date : ",[dateFormatterBegin stringFromDate:datebegin]];

            NSLog(@"Your date is : %@",beginDate); 

            [dateFormatterBegin release];
            [beginDate release];
```